# SQL SERVER - Select data of upcoming 30 days with 1 year more

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

For my project, I need to find a query which find data of upcoming 30 days with 1 year more.

Here's an example :

-I did a training the 2014-01-31 and to complete my training I need to do a reminder 1 year after (2015-01-31).

-BUT, I want to select this reminder in my database, 30 days minimum before the date of the reminder.

-SO, my goal is to have a reminder from the 2015-01-31 until to 2015-01-31.

Here's an example of my code, because of my bad English (I'm french IT student), I can't explain really good... :/

```
select nom, libelle_produit, nom_produit, date_debut_formation, date_fin_formation,
       DATEADD (day , 365 , date_fin_formation) as 'Date limite' 
from T_PRODUIT 
    join T_FORMATION  on T_FORMATION.id_produit=T_PRODUIT.id_produit 
    join T_SUIT on T_SUIT.id_formation=T_FORMATION.id_formation 
    join T_EMPLOYES on T_EMPLOYES.id_employe = T_SUIT.id_employe 
where DATEADD(year,1,year(date_fin_formation)) <= DATEADD(year,1,getdate())
  and DATEADD(month,1,month(date_fin_formation)) <= DATEADD(month,1,getdate())
  and DATEADD (day,1,day(date_fin_formation)) <= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
```

Could you help me please ? This don't give me a good result...

Comment: Its better if you show the data sample or a sql fiddle may be ..

Comment: Your goal have the same dates (2015-01-31),  Do you want to have a reminder from 2015-01-01 until 2015-01-31?

Comment: @JonathanLarouche : Yep, it's what I want ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want

All Reminders to be shown today if

- `date_fin_formation` is less than (Today's date - 1 yr) + 30 days
- `date_fin_formation` is greater than Today's date - 1 yr

i.e. notification should start from (Today's date - 1 yr) + 30 days and end till (Today's date - 1 yr)

You can use a WHERE clause like `DATEADD(year,1,date_fin_formation) BETWEEN  DATEADD(day,-30,getdate()) AND GETDATE()` and Your Query would be.

```
select nom, libelle_produit, nom_produit, date_debut_formation, date_fin_formation, DATEADD (day , 365 , date_fin_formation) as 'Date limite' 
  from T_PRODUIT 
    join T_FORMATION  on T_FORMATION.id_produit=T_PRODUIT.id_produit 
    join T_SUIT on T_SUIT.id_formation=T_FORMATION.id_formation 
    join T_EMPLOYES on T_EMPLOYES.id_employe = T_SUIT.id_employe 
     WHERE DATEADD(year,1,date_fin_formation) BETWEEN  DATEADD(day,-30,getdate()) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: Oh god, it's work ! I just changed the between to get the 30 upcoming days and 10 previous days ! Thanks !
`WHERE DATEADD(year,1,date_fin_formation) BETWEEN  DATEADD(day,-10,getdate()) AND DATEADD(day,+30,getdate())`